# Inner Join in ON statement

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am working on an assignment:

> Compare the average daily revenue (as I define it in Teradata Week 5
>   Exercise Guide) of the store with the highest msa_income and the store
>   with the lowest median msa_income (according to the msa_income field).
>   In what city and state were these two stores, and which store had a
>   higher average daily revenue?

... and the answer key has a inner join in `ON` statement, which confused me a lot. I have only learnt Join in `FROM`. So I searched online about an inner join in `ON` statement, there was not much about it.

I am a new learner, so this question might be really basic. Thanks in advance for your patience!

The line I where I had a problem is: `ON m.store=t.store JOIN strinfo s`

```
SELECT SUM(store_rev. tot_sales)
    SUM(store_rev.numdays) AS daily_average, 
    store_rev.msa_income as med_income,     
    store_rev.city, store_rev.state
    FROM (SELECT COUNT (DISTINCT t.saledate) as numdays, 
    EXTRACT(YEAR from t.saledate) as s_year, 
    EXTRACT(MONTH from t.saledate) as s_month, t.store, 
    sum(t.amt) as tot_sales, 
    CASE 
       when extract(year from t.saledate) = 2005 AND extract(month from t.saledate) = 8 then 'exclude'
END as exclude_flag, m.msa_income, s.city, s.state
FROM trnsact t JOIN store_msa m
ON m.store=t.store JOIN strinfo s
ON t.store=s.store
WHERE t.stype = 'P' AND exclude_flag IS NULL
GROUP BY s_year, s_month, t.store, m.msa_income, s.city, s.state
HAVING numdays >= 20) as store_rev
WHERE store_rev.msa_income IN ((SELECT MAX(msa_income) 
FROM store_msa),(SELECT MIN(msa_income) FROM store_msa))
GROUP BY med_income, store_rev.city, store_rev.state;
```

Comment: Thanks for your edition! It is indeed much easier to read now. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps it would be easier to follow if written like this:

```
FROM trnsact t JOIN
     store_msa m
     ON m.store = t.store JOIN
     strinfo s
     ON t.store = s.store
```

The `JOIN` isn't *in* the `ON` statement.  The `FROM` clause consists of multiple joins, chained together.

You can think of the `JOIN` keyword as ending the `ON` clause and starting a new join condition.

Comment: Thank you for answering.  So,  the first SELECT in FROM clause is selecting from the result of join from table: trnsact, store_msa AND strinfo .RIght?   It is the same as:  FROM trnsact t, store_msa m, strinfo s  ON m.store=t.store AND t.store=s.store.

Comment: @JuneChoo . . . Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  Always use explicit `JOIN` syntax.